# How do you change a fieldName via mongoose method + change it in schema?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, schema

I have a schema like this:

```
const StorySchema = new Schema({
    authorId: String,
    title: String,
    longUrl: String,
    shortUrl: String,
    comment: String,
    category: String,
    author: String,
    date: { type: Date, default: Date.now, index: true },
    votes: { type: Number, default: 1, index: true },
});
```

I want to change the votes field on the schema to be called votesCount and at the same time I want to actually change the schema.

Would I just do these in the same file?

```
const StorySchema = new Schema({
    authorId: String,
    title: String,
    longUrl: String,
    shortUrl: String,
    comment: String,
    category: String,
    author: String,
    date: { type: Date, default: Date.now, index: true },
    votesCount: { type: Number, default: 1, index: true },
});

const StoryModel = mongoose.model('story', StorySchema);

StoryModel.update({}, { $rename: { votes: 'votesCount' } }, { multi: true, strict: false }, function(err, blocks) { });
```

Or do I not do this at all in the code? I have never dealt with database schema changes, so I'm not sure how / where to apply schema changes.

Comment: That's a code deployment issue. To change a schema on a model at run-time you would need to de-register the current model and then register again with a new schema change. If all you are doing is "deploying a change to production", then all you should do it stop your program access momentarily and update the actual data then restart with the changed code.

Answer (score 0):

Make your changes in the Schema and the controller, as whatever name you use in your Schema field should also tally with the one in your Controller.

Eg.

```
const StorySchema = new Schema({

authorId: String,
title: String,
longUrl: String,
shortUrl: String,
comment: String,
category: String,
author: String,
date: { type: Date, default: Date.now, index: true },
votesCount: { type: Number, default: 1, index: true },
});
```

In your controller

```
let form = {
            authorId:req.body.*****,
            title:req.body.*****,
            longUrl:req.body.*****,
            shortUrl:req.body.*****,
            comment:req.body.*****,
            category:req.body.*****,
            author:req.body.*****,
            date:req.body.*****,
            votesCount:req.body.*****
        };
```

Note: the main point am trying to make here is that, the very name you used in the Schema should also the the same name you're gonna use for your controller.

I hope this is answers your question.

Answer (score -1):

best use updateMany as

```
db.students.updateMany( {}, { $rename: { "nmae": "name" } } )
```

and change in your controller or directly replace previous field name to new field name where ever possible.

My Suggestion is better u first replace in controller or your project and if your project running in production update your new controller than u replace the field name using $rename